# How to update nested object field in MongoDB document via Mongoose Node.js ORM?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, coffeescript, mongoose

I can't figure out how to change the value of a field in a nested document in a MongoDB document via the Mongoose Node.js JavaScript ORM. Code in CoffeeScript:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
mongoose.connect 'mongodb://localhost/test'
Schema = mongoose.Schema

Page = new Schema
  content: String

Article = new Schema
  _id: String
  pages: [Page] 

article_model = mongoose.model 'Article', Article, 'testcollection'

article_model.findOne({_id: 'id1'}, (err, article) =>
  article.pages[0].content = 'foo'
  article.save()
)
```

The next time I fetch `article`, `article.pages[0].content` still has its original value, although there is no error on the `save()`.

I suspect I need to reference `content` differently... but how? Thanks!

Edit: It works if I do something like this:

```
for page in article.pages
  if page is whatever
    page.content = 'foo'
article.save()
```

However, that seems pretty inelegant and inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) function.